# topology on varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, and the topology I am talking about is the Eucliden topology.

I am not sure if the following two results are true, and where can I find the references:

(1) If $X,Y$ are birational then they have the same fundamental group.

(2) If $X$ is contractible (or maybe simply connected), then it only has trivial line bundle.

Comment: The parenthetical guess in (2) is too strong already  for $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Comment: An easy counter-example to (1) is given by considering $\mathbb{C}^* \subset \mathbb{C}$. I think in (1) if you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-singular and projective then what you want is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) is not correct unless you assume your varieties to be smooth and projective; for instance $\Bbb{P}^1$ with 2 points identified is not simply connected. In the smooth projective case it is true, see SGA 1.

In (2), I assume you are talking about *topological* classification of line bundles. They are classified by their first Chern class, so if $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is zero (in particular if $X$ is contractible), every line bundle is topologically trivial. But any smooth projective variety of dimension $>0$ has a nontrivial line bundle, and many of them are simply connected.

Comment: In(1), by simply connect do you mean in the Euclidean topology or Etale topology? (2) So there is a differences between "algebraic bundle" and "topological bundle"?

Comment: (1): no difference in this case. (2): Yes! Maybe you should start by some basic book in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Usually line bundles are "classified" by $H^2$. By Cartan's Theorem B, for Stein manifolds (therefore smooth affine varieties), holomorphic lines bundles are completely classified by $H^2$.